# Getting full IP address to show in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

The code below seems to only return the first two digits of my IP address.  How can I get the full IP address?

```
$ip2 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

**EDIT:**  I'm putting it into MySQL as varchar(30) latin1_swedish_ci.  Is there a format change that will show the full IP?

**EDIT 2:**  Maybe it's my query that's changing the format.  Here it is:

```
$query1 = sprintf("INSERT INTO values VALUES (NULL, 'phoenix', %d, '%s', %d, %d, %d, NULL)", $submissionid, $fullurl, $uid, $ip1, $ip2);

mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Are you running it on localhost or an external server?  Are you saving it to a database or just echoing it?

Comment: Can you show more of your code?  That should give the whole IP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with

```
$ip2 = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

You say it only seems to contain the first two digits, but I'm guessing you made this assumption because `$query1` only contains that.

The problem is that you're using `%d` in [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf) which attempts to get the integer value of `$ip2`. An IP address is not an integer, but a string, thus you should use `%s`.

```
sprintf("INSERT INTO values VALUES (NULL, 'phoenix', %d, '%s', %d, '%s', '%s', NULL)",
     $submissionid, $fullurl, $uid, $ip1, $ip2);
```

Answer (score 2):

I concur that this PHP is fine.

BUT...

Storing in a varchar(30) is a **bad** idea.  You seem to be assuming that you will always get an IPv4 address.  You won't.

Take, for example:

2001:470:1f04:de:22cf:30ff:feb0:e22b

That won't fit in your field!

Answer (score 0):

putting %s instead of %d will work in inserting the ip address.